# ole container close function triggers EOleSysError when app terminated via Task Manager

Tags: delphi, ole

I am opening MS Word in a TOLEContainer. I have noticed that if this is not shut down properly by calling `OLEContainer1.close`it leaves a background MS Word app running. This then prevents the oleContainer loading a word document. The app containing the OLECOntainer simply hangs on the call to create object until the word process is terminated via the Task Manager.

Provided the user closes the form normally the call to `OLEContainer1.close` in the FormClose event operates as expected. However, if you unexpectedly abort the app (eg via Task Manager) the call to the close function throws up an EOleSysError with the description:

> An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching
>   an input-synchronous call

I have read up as to the meaning of this message and whilst I basically understand what is going on I have no idea how to call the close function in an abort situation so as not to cause the error to be raised.

Comment: What Windows, Delphi and Word versions?  I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe.  `Microsoft Office Word` only appears in Task Manager if I dbl-click the TOleContainer to activate Word in the container.  If I then kill Word in Task Manager, the Word instance in the container disappears and the Delphi app can then be closed without complaint, leaving no Word instance in Task Manager.

Comment: Delphi 10.2. Word. Office 365 ProPlus Version 1708. Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with the call to `OLEContainer1.Close` in the `FormClose` event. If this is omitted then the Word application is terminated even when crashing out. I thought it was necessary to close the container before exiting, but seemingly not. I was also calling `DestroyObject`, but it seems that is done automatically when releasing the object.